# Explain string boolean test result

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
>>> char = 'A'
>>> 'A' == char
True
>>> ('A' or 'B') == char
True
```

Why does this not equal `True`?

```
>>> ('B' or 'A') == char
False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expressions are not doing what you expect.

```
'A' or 'B'
```

This actually evaluates to `'A'`, try it out in the interpreter!

When you say

```
('A' or 'B') == char
```

The interpreter is actually doing these steps:

```
('A' or 'B') == char
('A') == char
True
```

But when you do

```
('B' or 'A') == char
```

The interpreter does this:

```
('B' or 'A') == char
('B') == char
False
```

What you probably wanted was:

```
'A' == char or 'B' == char
True
```

Comment: thank you , but I find it pretty counter intuitive. Why ('A' or 'B') == char option is even allowed in that case?

Comment: Because it's a legitimate comparison.  I think you'll find that `python` is as good or better in regards to not letting you do things you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is how those expressions evaluate:

```
In [1]: 'A' or 'B'
Out[1]: 'A'

In [3]: 'B' or 'A'
Out[3]: 'B'
```

...therefore, 'B' or 'A' shouldn't equal `char` in your case.

For details on how `or` should work, consult the ["Boolean operations" section of the python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#or):

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

That ordering described above is critical and includes a concept called "[lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)."

Answer (score 2):

the comparisons you're doing actually compares the boolean values of `'A'` and `'B'`.

so : `('A' or 'B')` is actually `(bool('A') or bool('B')`, as it's a `or` condition and as `bool('A')` is `True` in first case so it compares `'A'==char` , and in second case as `bool('B')` is True so it compares `'B'==char`( which is `False`)

```
In [114]: False or True
Out[114]: True

In [115]: True or False
Out[115]: True

In [116]: True or True
Out[116]: True

In [117]: bool('A')
Out[117]: True

In [118]: bool('B')
Out[118]: True
```

this is how it happens in background:\

```
In [104]: def func():
    char="A"
    return ('A' or 'B')==char
   .....: 

In [107]: def func1():
    char="A"
    return ("B" or "A")==char
   .....: 

In [110]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')  
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (char)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')   #loads 'A'
              9 JUMP_IF_TRUE             4 (to 16)  # if 'A' is True then go to 16
                                                    # As 'A' is not a falsy value so it                                                                                                         
                                                     goes to  16
             12 POP_TOP                  
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 ('B')
        >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (char)  #load char , i.e 'A'
             19 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)    #compare 'A'=='A' , i,e True
             22 RETURN_VALUE        

In [111]: dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (char)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('B')      #load 'B', it's a true value
                                                      # so go to 16
              9 JUMP_IF_TRUE             4 (to 16)
             12 POP_TOP             
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
        >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (char)     #load chr ,i.e 'A'
             19 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)       #'B'=='A' , False
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```